# Derivative of solution to IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have two IVPs as followings:
$$
y'=f(y, t)+g(y, t) \tag{1}
$$
$$
y'=f(y, t)\tag{2}
$$
with the same initial condition $y(t_0)=y_0$. Both $y$ and $t$ are positive and bounded.

Furthermore, $f(y, t)$ and $g(y, t)$ satisfy that

(i) both $f(y, t)$ and $g(y, t)$ are positive for all $t$ in the domain.

(ii) both $f(y, t)$ and $g(y, t)$ are uniformly Lipschitz continuous w.r.t. y and t.

(iii) $f_y(y, t)<0$, $f_t(y, t)>0$, $f_{yt}(y, t)<0$ and $g_t(y, t)>0$.

The existence and uniqueness of solution to the IVPs are given by uniformly Lipschitz continuity. Denote $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$ the solution to the first and second IVP respectively.

It is not difficult to see that $y_1(t)\geq y_2(t)$. However since $f_y(y, t)<0$, it is difficult for me to see if 
$$
y'_1(t)\geq y'_2(t)
$$

for all $t$ or not.

If the above assumptions do not suffice to prove that $y'_1(t)\geq y'_2(t)$ for all $t$. What kind of assumptions (hopefully mild) do I need in addition?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: Nice question. For sure you noticed that $y_1(t)\ge y_2(t)$. What have you tried for the derivative?

Comment: My apology that I was sloppy before. Please check out the revised question. Hopefully it is clear now.